# Capture key events page-wide

Tags: html

How to capture all keyboard events on a web page using HTML5? How to check whether ALT or CTRL key is pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind `keypress` to the `document`. (Broad question, broad answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [jQuery keypress function](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) to capture the keypress.

Example to detect Ctrl-S:

`$(window).keypress(function(event) {
    if (!(event.which == 115 && event.ctrlKey) && !(event.which == 19)) return true;
    alert("Ctrl-S pressed");
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});`

Key codes can differ between browsers, so you may need to check for more than just 115.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few libraries focusing on capturing global key events, including short-cuts to identify metakeys like control/command/shift. You can pick a library or learn from them:

- https://keithamus.github.io/jwerty/
- https://github.com/madrobby/keymaster